# JS Tree set up for external ajax

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am developing an application that uses JS Tree with json data and ajax per the documentation at http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data.

```
$("#tree).jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "ajax": { ... }
    } ....
});
```

There are also other jquery ajax calls being made elsewhere in the document. Right now, the tree makes its ajax calls within its own name space so there are no conflicts with the other ajax functions. Because of issues with the server that answers the ajax calls, I need to redirect the tree’s ajax calls through the common ajax handler the rest of the document uses and then have that handler return the data back to the tree.

Can anyone suggest how to redirect the tree’s calls to another function and set up the callback to return the data back to the tree? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to redirect? Or what do you want to change in regards to the default jsTree ajax call?

Comment: @Radek Right now jstree makes an ajax call to get child nodes. The tree then adds those nodes. It is all handled within jstree. I would like the tree to call an external function that will make the ajax call and either 1) return the child node info back to the tree or 2) have the external function add the nodes. I think I will have to change line 92 of the json plugin from "return $.ajax(s.ajax);" to something like "return [external function that uses $.ajax(parent node);]".

Comment: Why do you want external function to add nodes?

Comment: @Radek Long story made short... There are issues with the server operation (there are modes) where it will not return the node data to the request made by the tree, but will return the data during the next request. This is part of a security system that can interrupt the ajax responses to do user verification. If I rout all ajax call through a handler, I can rout all responses to the right place when they do arrive. i.e. User verification to the proper dialog and tree nodes to the tree regardless of the order in which they are received. I know it is a strange system, it is what I have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an idea. Not sure if it will fit your requirements, and probably you will need to work it out a little bit more, but it's somehow close to what I've understood from your question:

The **json_data plugin**, as stated in the [documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data), is pretty much the same as the [jQuery ajax settings object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

With this in mind, you can redirect/conduct the ajax query to a custom function making use of the `beforeSend() callback function`

```
    "json_data": { 
        "ajax": {
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                my_custom_function(xhr);
            }
        }
    }
```

And define a custom function where you can take over the **XHR object** and adjust it to your needs:

```
function my_custom_function(xhr) {
    $.ajax($.extend(xhr, {
        type: 'GET',
        url:  '/folders/tree_handler.json',
        data: { 
            "operation": "get_children", 
            "parent_id": 1
        }
    }));

    return false;
}
```

What I'm doing here is setting up the URL, the request type (GET) and a couple of parameters that you could want to pass to the custom function as another object, ot whatever is more convenient (for instance you will want the parent_id to be variable).

You will need to return **false** in this custom function so the first caller request gets canceled.

Please let me know if it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was aware of and do use the global .ajaxSend() to call a function prior to an ajax call. but I was unaware of the beforeSend() callback. It looks promising. I just got very bussy with other stuff, but when I get time I will dig into the documentation and see if I can get this to work. I'll keep you posted.